# How can I reorder this file's data for better compression?

Tags: compression

I have a file of pieces of data that can be reordered arbitrarily. Each piece of data is typically around 0-300 bytes. What tools or algorithms are out there that I can use to reorder them so that the compressed version of the file is smaller? It has to be compressed (for various reasons) using `zip` in `deflate` mode, level 6.

Things like the Needleman-Wunsch algorithm and the Burrows-Wheeler algorithm seem promising, but perhaps I need something more specifically tailored to this case.

Comment: It depends almost exclusively on the data type. "to reorder them" what do you mean? I'm pretty sure that reordering data doesn't, or hardly, matters

Comment: The data here is the symbols of a binary. So, strings, functions in assembly, etc. It seems that reordering data *can* be helpful, which is why the Burrows-Wheeler transform is a thing in the first place.

Comment: Sorry not in my field, but take a look to Huffman coding, it's very effective with binary data. sometime up to 90% lossless compression.